# Writing a programming language: how to compile

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

I am writing a simple programming language (in Python, if that matters) to test my regex parsing skills, and I came up with a question: should my compiler convert code into C++ code and then use g++ to compile it to ELF executable, or should I somehow manage to compile my language's code into bytecode (or anything else)?

Comment: Most programming languages aren't parseable with plain old regexes. Yes, this will test your skills; you will probably fail; and the question will be, what did you learn?  The  lesson learned repeatedly be people do this kind of exercise is that writing a "compiler" without having paid any attention to the literature leads to bad results.  And, nobody is surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do that. For example, the original implementation of C++ ("C with Classes") converted the C++ code to C code, which was compiled with a regular  C compiler. Of course, that's not how it works any more.

Your best bet would be to start with GCC or LLVM and write a new-front end for your language, leveraging the existing code generation tools for the numerous architectures.